# Trying to send data from query to another function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**first i have two problem here the first problem when i run this query it gives me this Error**
**//ERROR**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3909.6209753917' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `user_data`.`avatar` from `users` inner join `user_data` on `user_data`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and (`user_data`.`city` LIKE %tripoli% and `user_data`.`address` LIKE %ain zara% and `users`.`is_admin` is null and `users`.`is_store` is null and `user_data`.`active` = 1 and `user_data`.`anyOrders` = 1 and `3909`.`6209753917` <= 3))
```

second Problem in where([]) i try to call a function and i send with function pramters but first two paramter go as string i'm trying to send data from user_data Table
**look here**

```
where([
      ['user_data.city','LIKE', '%' .  $store->city . '%'],
      ...
      [$this-**>haversineGreatCircleDistance('user_data.lat','user_data.lon',$store->lat,$store->lon), '<=', '3']
    ]**);
```

**here is complete function**

```
public function searchNearUsers($id) { 
  $store = storeData::where('store_id',auth()->user()->id)->first();
         
  $users = User::join('user_data', function ($join) use ($store) {             
    $join->on('user_data.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->where([
      ['user_data.city','LIKE', '%' .  $store->city . '%'],
      ['user_data.address','LIKE', '%' .  $store->address . '%'],
      ['users.is_admin', '=', NULL],
      ['users.is_store', '=', NULL],
      ['user_data.active', '=', 1],
      ['user_data.anyOrders', '=', 1],
      [$this->haversineGreatCircleDistance('user_data.lat','user_data.lon',$store->lat,$store->lon), '<=', '3']
    ]);
  })->select('users.*', 'user_data.avatar')
  ->get();

  dd($users);
  
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: You've described a (relatively vague) requirement, but you haven't explained what problem you're having specifically with this code right now. It's not clear what the issue is or what you need help with. See [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: looks like you missed the column name and have entered the numerical value instead `[$this.....` might need to be `['user_data.column', $this->.......` or maybe wrap it in quotes? Hard to tell what you want

Comment: That's not a grammatical sentence and I for one have no idea what it means, sorry. Take the time to write clearly, with punctuation, and be precise too - remember we cannot read your mind. If writing in English is difficult for you, please find someone to help you translate properly, so your comments will not be ambiguous. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find below code
Need '%abc%' single quote "'" for like query

```
public function searchNearUsers($id) { 
  $store = storeData::where('store_id',auth()->user()->id)->first();
         
  $users = User::join('user_data', function ($join) use ($store) {             
    $join->on('user_data.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->where([
      ['user_data.city','LIKE', "'%" .  $store->city . "%'"],
      ['user_data.address','LIKE', "'%" .  $store->address . "%'"],
      ['users.is_admin', '=', NULL],
      ['users.is_store', '=', NULL],
      ['user_data.active', '=', 1],
      ['user_data.anyOrders', '=', 1],
      [$this->haversineGreatCircleDistance('user_data.lat','user_data.lon',$store->lat,$store->lon), '<=', '3']
    ]);
  })->select('users.*', 'user_data.avatar')
  ->get();

  dd($users);
  
  return redirect()->back();
}
```